# Negation (complement) of Less-than, Greater-than etc

Tags: boolean-logic

What is the negation (complement) of:

`i < A.Length`

in the context of:

```
Do (i < A.Length )   // is it i == A.Length  or   i > A.Length   ?
```

What is the negation of

`i <= A.Length`

in the context of:

```
Do (i <= A.Length )  // is it  i >= A.Length  ?
```

For some reason I can't find a source to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just to draw a line with 0 in the middle. Then, all that is to right of zero is `> 0`, so the complement is another part of the line. And it is `< 0` and `0`. So, the complement to `> 0` is `<= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of < is >= and the complement of > is <= though without understanding what i is, relative to the .length properties, that operation may not be quite what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Negation of `i < A.Length` is `i >= A.Length` and negation of `i <= A.Length` is `i > A.Length`.